Java what happens when a more specific method is found during runtime for dynamic binding?
In my college class, we recently learnt about dynamic binding and I faced this particular question:
Consider the following relationships between classes: WTC <: Skyscraper <: Building. We have two classes A and B. The type of the argument to the method foo has been omitted.
class A {

public void foo(Building f) { }

}

class B extends A {

public void foo(_BLANK_ f) { }

}

Consider the code snippet below:
Skyscraper skyscraper;

Building building = new Skyscraper();

building.foo(skyscaper);

Among the four possible types: WTC, Skyscraper, Building, and Object, what could "BLANK" be such that the call to a.foo() above invokes A::foo?

A. WTC only
B. WTC or Skyscaper only
C. WTC or Object only
D. Skyscraper or Building only
E. Skyscraper, Building, or Object only
F. None of the options are correct.

The given answer is F and I know that using Building in Class B would lead to B::foo() to be invoked but why is Skyscraper still allowed to be used in B::foo()? I was told that we were supposed to find the most specific method and at Compile Time it is A::foo(Building f) so at runtime it will attempt to find this method signature only. But realistically shouldn't the JVM at runtime notice that B::foo(Skyscraper f) is more specific than A::foo(Building f)?
I'm quite puzzled and am not sure why so. Am I missing something? Apologies but I couldn't find much help on Google.

You declared a foo method in A and B. Is the second code snippet supposed to be A building = new B();?

the method signature is determined at compile time - the signature includes the name and the formal parameter types - foo(Skyscraper) is not the same method as foo(Building), it is not overriding it

Your code example doesn't compile: Building doesn't declare a method called foo. But from context, I gather you want to know why
    A a = new B();
    a.foo(new SkyScraper());

invokes A.foo(Building) rather than B.foo(SkyScraper)?

I was told that we were supposed to find the most specific method and at Compile Time it is A::foo(Building f) so at runtime it will attempt to find this method signature only.

That is correct. To elaborate a bit, method resolution happens in two major steps:

At compile time, the compiler uses the type the method is being invoked on, and the types of the arguments provided, to find the signature of the method to be invoked (of which there may be several due to overloading), and writes the reference to that method signature into the classfile.
At runtime, the runtime selects which implementation of that method to use (of which there may be several due to overriding) based on the runtime type of the object whose method is invoked.

That is, variance in parameters is resolved at compile time, based on compile-time type information, while variance in the receiver type is ultimately resolved at runtime, based on the runtime type of the receiver object.
And that explains why the parameters must not vary if the runtime is to select the "more specific" method.
Not quite convinced? No problem, the actual normative description of how Java resolves a method invocation expression is given in section 15.12 of the Java Language Specification, so let's go through that and see how it applies to
a.foo(new SkyScraper())


15.12.1. Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Type to Search
The first step in processing a method invocation at compile time is to figure out the name of the method to be invoked and which type to search for definitions of methods of that name.

The name is foo, and the type to search for is the declared type of the variable a, which is A.

15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature
The second step searches the type determined in the previous step for member methods. This step uses the name of the method and the argument expressions to locate methods that are both accessible and applicable, that is, declarations that can be correctly invoked on the given arguments.

There is one method foo in A, it is accessible, and also appliccable, because its parameter type Building does accept a SkyScraper.

There may be more than one such method, in which case the most specific one is chosen. The descriptor (signature plus return type) of the most specific method is the one used at run time to perform the method dispatch.

Nope, there is only one method, so it is, by definition, the most appliccable, and the descriptor written to the class file is:
void A.foo(Building)


15.12.3. Compile-Time Step 3: Is the Chosen Method Appropriate?

Having chosen the method, the compiler now checks some further conditions that must be met for the method to be invoked. Since this doesn't change which method is chosen, we won't dig into this here.

15.12.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation
At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. Second, the argument expressions are evaluated. Third, the accessibility of the method to be invoked is checked. ...

In our case, this means:

the target reference is a, which references an object of class B.
the argument expression new SkyScraper() is evaluated, yielding a new object of class SkyScraper.
the accessibility is ok


15.12.4.4. Locate Method to Invoke

This section contains a deeply nested list of cases, the relevant one being

Otherwise, overriding may occur. A dynamic method lookup, specified below, is used to locate the method to invoke. The lookup procedure starts from class R, the actual run-time class of the target object.

which is B.

The procedure for dynamic method lookup is as follows. Let S be the class to search, beginning with R. Then:

If class S contains a declaration for a method that overrides method m of class or interface C from R (§8.4.8.1), then that overriding method is the method to be invoked, and the procedure terminates.
Otherwise, if S has a superclass, then steps 1 and 2 of this lookup procedure are performed recursively using the direct superclass of S in place of S; the method to be invoked, if any, is the result of the recursive invocation of this lookup procedure.
If no method is found by the previous two steps, the superinterfaces of S are searched for a suitable method. [...]


That is, we ask whether B declares a method that overrides A.foo(Building). Alas, the method B.foo(SkyScraper) can not override A.foo(Building), because

An instance method mC declared in or inherited by class C, overrides from C another method mA declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:

...
...
The signature of mC is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of mA as a member of the supertype of C that names A.


and that is defined by

Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.
The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:

m2 has the same signature as m1, or
the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.


Nope, Building and ScyScraper are different types, and their erasures are different, too.
Therefore, foo(ScyScraper) is not a subsignature of foo(Building), and B.foo(ScyScraper) can not override A.foo(Building).
And so, the search for a method foo that takes a Building continues with the superclass of B, A, where we find A.foo(Building), and invoke it.
This makes sense: after all, the compiler allows us to write a.foo(new Doghouse()), because A.foo(Building) accepts any Building. The runtime must therefore cope with any kind of Building as well. In theory, it could select a different method based on the runtime type of the objects being passed, but that would make method resolution at runtime far more complicated and therefore slow. Since invoking methods is a very common thing, and such ultra-dynamic resolution very rarely useful, that would make the language considerably slower for little benefit.
Overloading also has corner cases overriding does not. For instance if I write
bar(new SkyScraper(), new ScyScraper());

how should the runtime choose between bar(Building, SkyScraper) and bar(SkyScraper, Building)? Neither is more specific than the other! The compiler would emit a compilation error here, does this mean the runtime should throw an exception???
In summary, method selection based on parameters is far to complicated to do at runtime, which is why Java does it at compile time based on compile-time types.
